# How to Change the color of marker

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

[image: image having 6 marker]

I want to change the color of all marker in sequence one by one just feel like marker color is moving. 
for example- when first marker color change from blue to red. After one second next marker color will be change from blue to red..but then previous marker color will be changed again red to blue..

Mean there will be only one marker whose color can be red one at a time.
Please help me to get this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If latitude and longitude of marker equal to current latitude and longitude then change to red else blue

Comment: Keep a state for current marker location (lat,lng) and change current state when you want